# No font size property for text object in SVG-edit v2.7

Tags: svg-edit

Why is there no font size property for text object in SVG-edit v2.7?
Am I just suppose to resize the text object? How then do I make sure the proportions are kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all I need is to hold down the shift key while resizing so that proportions are kept. Thus no font size property needed I guess.